# (502 bad gateway) Ingress component , TLS backend

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress, tls1.2

So I have an HTTPS, TLS secured pod running ..

When I expose this pod using Load balancer service, the result is for HTTP requests:

[image: Load balancer service HTTP]

Which is normal because the service is HTTPS only, so when I send an HTTPS requests:

[image: Load Balancer service HTTPS]

This is my objects i had an ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE error because my service is protected with TLS and in my pod logs i get:

[image: Pod logs]

So all i want to do is to expose this service with ingress , first ingress didn't work at all and i get 400 error which was normal because i have HTTP backend the i added the HTTPS backend type and now i have 502 bad gateway always as a response

[image: 502 bad gateway]

And in the pod logs:

[image: TLS Handshake error]

this is my Ingress yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: south-service-ingress
  namespace: exmple
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-cf-prod"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - exemple.com
      secretName: exmple
  rules:
  - host: exemple.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: south-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Edit: i am adding the deployment yaml file for more info

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: south-service
  name: south-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: south-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: south-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: {{ .Values.southService.image.repository }}
          name: south-service

          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: {}
      imagePullSecrets: 
        - name: registry-credentials
```

Also for more details about the problem i made this schemas:

[image]

[image]

PS: For privacy reasons, I changed the host and namespace names to "example"

Any Help ??
I read this thread wish may be related but didn't work for me :
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6728

Answer (score 0):

1. You should first read the 2nd point. Then consider if there is any error in your issuer (like making sure it's in the same namespace, there are no typos, etc.)
2. If you're going to share your issuer please first take proper care of any sensitive information

https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/issuer/

If everything is in place, and you still have errors, I could update this answer if you provide new information or details.

Edit:
Don't take this as a rule or protocol you can do whatever you want.. Just think about it, what's the standard? Default port.. (right?).
My advise:
Your ingress should listen on 80, and use a Service to map ports.
Ingress will link your URLs to the appropriate pods.
I am mapping 443 in the Service however the only port declared in my Ingress is 80

Also, is this "*south-service-8080*" a service(?) a deployment(?) what is it?

Comment: Yes i am sure about the information of the issuer i am using it for another service and it works fine ✅

Comment: This is the logs of my ingress-controller-manager pod :

`10.100.19.203 - - [12/Jul/2022:14:09:20 +0000] "GET /api/v2/example HTTP/1.1" 502 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 219 0.007 [south-service-8080] [] 10.100.41.0:8080, 10.100.41.0:8080, 10.100.41.0:8080 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.004, 0.004 502, 502, 502 `

Comment: `de5c4e56-2916-4b61-ab43-cea04e0a52aa
2022/07/12 14:09:20 [crit] 9070#9070: *15916933 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1411713E:SSL routines:ssl_check_srvr_ecc_cert_and_alg:ecc cert not for signing error:14082130:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:bad ecc cert) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.100.19.203, server: example.com, request: "GET /api/v2/example HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.100.41.0:8080/api/v2/example", host: "example.com"`

Comment: @firasfendri updated. I cannot warranty this will solve your problem, so make sure you're doing it as a test to keep the state of the error (this question) clear create a branch or backup your files.
It could also be time consuming (if there is something you need to learn first)

Comment: It's a deployment i added the deployment code and also made some schemas to describe the problem, thank you for your help still stuck and couldn't find any useful information about my problem @Karmavil

Comment: @firasfendri I see, but your Ingress doesn't know that service right? I guess it's you who is doing that redirect. Are you using nginx? check your .conf files. You will probably have to change this "south-service-8080" to `https://south-service:8080`